# On First Click Link Button is not Firing/Working?

Tags: c#

Hi guys, I have a Link button. On first click it's not redirecting to target page and on second click it's working why?

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAttDetail" runat="server" Text='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "schdate") == DBNull.Value ? " " : Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("schdate").ToString()).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"))%>' CausesValidation="false"
                                     CssClass="navigationlink" CommandName='<% # Eval("schdate") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("schdate") + ";" + Eval("emp_id") %>' 
                                    OnClick="lnkAttDetail_Click" ForeColor="black" Font-Underline="false"  />

 protected void lnkAttDetail_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        LinkButton lnkAttDetail = (LinkButton)sender;
        string[] arguments = lnkAttDetail.CommandArgument.Split(';');
        string schdate = arguments[0];
        string id = arguments[1];


        lnkAttDetail.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;

        lnkAttDetail.PostBackUrl = string.Format("ManualAttendance.aspx?schdate={0}&id={1}", schdate, id) + "&M=" + Request.QueryString["M"] + "&S=" + int.Parse(Request.QueryString["S"].ToString()) + "&sys=" + ((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>)Session["User"])["Token"];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its working**, on first click you are setting `PostBackUrl` of link button you are not submitting it. Thus on working on second click. You can use `Response.Redirect` method

Use

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("ManualAttendance.aspx?schdate={0}&id={1}", schdate, id) 
    + "&M=" + Request.QueryString["M"]
    + "&S=" + int.Parse(Request.QueryString["S"].ToString()) 
    + "&sys=" 
    + ((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>)Session["User"])["Token"]);
```

instead of

```
lnkAttDetail.PostBackUrl = string.Format("ManualAttendance.aspx?schdate={0}&id={1}", schdate, id) 
    + "&M=" 
    + Request.QueryString["M"] 
    + "&S=" 
    + int.Parse(Request.QueryString["S"].ToString()) 
    + "&sys=" 
    + ((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>)Session["User"])["Token"];
```

Comment: @user3208937 Please don't only say thank u and mark the post(s) that where a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because you are setting the `PostBackUrl` on the first click.

The link button redirects to the URL set in it's `PostBackUrl` Property which is empty before first click.
if you want to redirect on the first click , you have to use :

```
Response.Redirect("YOUR GENERATED URL HERE");
```

**PostBackUrl** is a Property and not a method.